# When does iOS clean the local app ./tmp directories?

Tags: ios, filesystems, temporary-files, temporary-directory

When does iOS clean the local app `./tmp` directory?

Note that this is not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593900/iphone-storage-in-tmp-directory). I'm asking about the app specific temporary folder, not the system wide one.

You can use *iExplorer* to have a look at `./tmp` directories on non-jailbroken phones.

(Note: *I'm asking this out of curiosity only. I kind of suspect that these never get deleted unless you restore your phone from a backup or reinstall that particular app. But obviously you cannot count on that for semi-permanently storing cached files.*)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4), it *could* be **any** time, if the app is not executing:

> The system may also purge lingering files from this directory when your app is not running.

It's logical to assume if a) your app is not running; and b) your device is running low on storage, then it's highly likely the system will, *at some point*, purge the contents of `<Application_Home>/tmp/`.

It's also worth noting that the documentation states:

> Your app should remove files from this directory when it determines they are no longer needed.

The emphasis here being on the app developer to do their own housekeeping and not leave it for the OS to tidy up after them.