# sharing Image and Video using uiactivityviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiactivityviewcontroller, photosframework

Need to share both Image and Video using Photos Framework through uiactivityviewcontroller. I am able to share images. and i am also able to share videos by exporting. but each time exporting a video app size increases..

Answer (score 0):

Yes application size increases because `image` and `video` store in `tmp directory` so tmp data automatic cline. 
 more info then [read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593900/iphone-storage-in-tmp-directory)