# sudden /tmp cleanup in iOS 9 and above

Tags: ios, ios9, tmp

I have a small console app I'm using on my JB device (for debugging purposes), which i place in /tmp.
From my experience, up unil iOS 8.4, the /tmp folder was cleared only on boot.
But now, on occasion, the /tmp dir is cleared - I couldn't figure out the reason (the device didn't run dangerously low on disk space).
My questions are these:

1. What is the daemon responsible for clearing /tmp? What else does it do?
2. Is there a way to flag my directory in some way to prevent it's clearance?
3. Did something actually happened in the iOS 9 update, or is it just circumstantial?

Comment: I know about the similar question in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593900/iphone-storage-in-tmp-directory), but I can't find answers to the specific questions I listed

Comment: How are you able to access /tmp on iOS? Is this a jailbroken device? Or are you talking about your app's temp directory?

Comment: Yes, it is JB (edited to clarify)